# Basic C question: Reading a Subfile in C

Tags: c, file

I have an xml like file and I have to read only a part of the file.(subfile).
Then I have to search this subfile for some "strings".

I thought of reading a file from a start pointer till an end pointer(which would be the subfile). Then I should work with this subfile and inspect line by line of the subfile using fgets().

The trouble is, fgets seems to take only a file pointer as parameter :( 
Any ideas??

Comment: Use `fseek` to go to the start position.

Comment: Which system do you want to be compatible with? Are you looking for a pure ANSI C solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mmap()` on UNIX/Linux to map a file to memory. This should make it easier to isolate a part of the file and work with it. Your xml library will probably want a buffer if it parses raw data, so you can just pass it the mmap result.

Here is an excellent example of usage

http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/fahmy/cs503/mmap.txt